# Asp.net Web API returning null response

Tags: asp.net-web-api

am faced with a challenge for some time now. I have a `web service (asp.net web api)`, that consumes a certain api, after the consumption, my api will then send the consumed data to another external api. I use `REST Sharp` for my `data serialization` and `request`.

> But anytime i send this request. I get a null result.

Anybody to help?

Comment: I downvoted because [It's hard to answer a programming question without code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: okay, will do that now

Answer (score 0):

Sequel to my question above @igor, below is my code snippet

public object AccountOpening(JObject exRequest)
        {

```
    var Account = new AccountViewModel(exRequest.ToString());

               Account.cifID = "null";
                Account.AddrCategory = "Mailing";
                Account.Country = "NG";
                Account.HoldMailFlag = "N";
                Account.PrefAddr = "Y";
                Account.Language = "UK (English)";
                Account.IsMinor = "N";
                Account.IsCustNRE = "N";
                Account.DefaultAddrType = "Mailing";
                Account.Occupation = "OTH";
                Account.PhoneEmailType = "CELLPH";
 var serviceAPI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RemoteAPI"];

var request = new RestSharp.Serializers.Newtonsoft.Json.RestRequest();
                request.AddParameter("application/json", Account, ParameterType.RequestBody);
                request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
                request.Method = Method.POST;
                request.JsonSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.JsonSerializer();

                var client = new RestClient(serviceAPI);
                IRestResponse resp = client.Post(request);

 if (resp.IsSuccessful==true)
                {
return Json(new {resp.Content });
}
```

}